# C++ cannot convert from base A to derived type B via virtual base A

Tags: c++, casting, downcast, virtual-inheritance, static-cast

I have four classes:

```
class A {};

class B : virtual public A {};
class C : virtual public A {};

class D: public B, public C {};
```

Attempting a static cast from A* to B* I get the below error:

```
cannot convert from base A to derived type B via virtual base A
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In order to understand the cast system, you need to dive into the object model.

The classic representation of a simple hierarchy model is containment: if `B` derives from `A` then the `B` object will, in fact, contain an `A` subobject alongside its own attributes.

With this model downcasting is a simple pointer manipulation by an offset known at compilation time, which depends on the memory layout of `B`.

This is what **static_cast** does: a static cast is dubbed static because the computation of what is necessary for the cast is done at compile-time, be it pointer arithmetic or conversions (*).

However, when `virtual` inheritance kicks in, things tend to become a bit more difficult. The main issue is that with `virtual` inheritance all subclasses share the same instance of the subobject. In order to do that, `B` will have a pointer to an `A`, instead of an `A` proper, and the `A` base class object will be instantiated outside of `B`.

Therefore, it's impossible at compilation time to be able to deduce the necessary pointer arithmetic: it depends on the runtime type of the object.

Whenever there is a runtime type dependency, you need RTTI (RunTime Type Information), and making use of RTTI for casts is the job of **dynamic_cast**.

In summary:

- compile-time downcast: `static_cast`
- run-time downcast: `dynamic_cast`

The other two are also compile-time casts, but they are so specific that it's easy to remember what they are for... and they are smelly, so better not use them at all anyway.

(*) *As noted by @curiousguy in the comments, this only holds for downcasting. A `static_cast` allows upcasting regardless of virtual or simple inheritance, though then the cast is also unnecessary.*

Comment: Nice answer which made me understand how virtual inheritance actually works ! +1

Comment: I like your answer, but the OP was apparently asking about an error for DOWNCASTING rather than upcasting.

Comment: @h9uest: Thanks for pointing out the slip-up, I changed "up-casting" to "downcasting" and everything is now well.

Comment: False. `static_cast` can be used to convert a derived ptr to a virtual base ptr.

Comment: @curiousguy: Indeed... although you don't even need a cast then, so I didn't think about taking it into account. Which begs the question why downcasting is not available too.

Comment: Converting to a base class is possible for non-polymorphic classes. `dynamic_cast` is only possible for polymorphic classes: `dynamic_cast` means "uses the vptr" (in most cases). A conversion to a virtual base class uses either the vptr or an internal pointer (or a fixed offset when the final complete type is known).

Comment: @curiousguy, @matthieu-m: I do not agree. `static_cast` makes the cast at run time. Upcast (without a cast expression) is also done at run time. Although it is true, that the compiled code is shorter than for `dynamic_cast`. For pointers `static_cast` compiles an `if != nullptr`, and then adds an offset **known at compile time**. However, if virtual inheritance is included, `static_cast` and upcast also compiles an `if != nullptr`, and then adds an offset **known at run time**. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/tSSSyq). `static_cast` can also call ctors., which is also entirely run time.

Comment: @Dr.Gut You made many pts here. 1) "_can also call ctors._" Indeed `static_cast` can do many thing. I thought we were discussing ptr casts here, not implicit conv in general or how to construct an obj. 2) Can we agree that the context is: doing the same conversion from type X to type Y either impl., w/ some casting oper or another. 3) Can you describe X and Y such that these choices are valid and **give diff compiled code?**

Comment: @curiousguy: **1)** The (*) sentence ends with "or conversions". So I thought it wants to be general. I edited the answer. It seems clearer now. Hope you will like it. First part is about containment: offset is known at compile-time whether up or downcast. Second part: about virtual inheritance (downcast gives error message, upcast possible, but offset is known at run-time).  **2)** Let's focus on casts between related class type pointers. Otherwise the terms compile-time and run-time get easily misinterpreted. **3)** I don't get what you are asking for. What choices?

Comment: @Dr.Gut 1) You wanted to be general but seemed to imply that a `static_cast` would always apply a fixed constant offset. 3) The choices of two conversion X and Y, from U->V between a "new style" cast `*_cast`, old style cast, implicit conversion for two given types U,V. In which case are X and Y a) both valid b) different at code gen level?

Comment: @curiousguy: Still not sure what you are asking for. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/FJzBDy) probably is not new to you. So I do not know. Maybe there is no such example. Ask it as a question here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, you need to use `dynamic_cast` because the inheritance is `virtual` and you're downcasting.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `static_cast` in this situation because the compiler doesn't know the offset of B relative to A at compile time. The offset must be calculated at run-time based on the exact type of the most derived object. Therefore you must use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: When converting a derived to a virtual base, you can use `static_cast`.

Comment: @curiousguy: yes, but the question is about converting base to derived.

Comment: It isn't clear why your argument doesn't apply to derived to base also.

Comment: @curiousguy: well, if you're asking why, then I think it is a good question and I'm not sure what the answer is. I speculate that this is because the derived to base cast is a matter of a simple indirection through the vtable, For the base to derived cast, on the other hand, you must perform the same (non constant time) algorithm as dynamic_cast does for the non-virtual inheritance. Thus there otherwise would not be a difference between static and dynamic casts for virtual inheritance. Or put another way, there is no analogy for non-virtual static_cast in the virtual-inheritance case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to use a dynamic_cast, but you'll have to make the base class A polymorphic, e.g. by adding a virtual dtor.

Comment: or adding at least one virtual method.

Answer (score 4):

According standard docs,

Section *5.2.9 - 9*, for **Static Cast**,

> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to cv2
>   D,” where D is a class derived (clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B”
>   exists (4.10), cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and **B is neither a virtual base class
>   of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D.**

Hence, it is not possible and you should use `dynamic_cast`...

Answer (score 1):

> $5.2.9/2- "An expression e can be
>   explicitly converted to a type T using
>   a static_cast of the form
>   static_cast(e) if the declaration
>   “T t(e);” is well-formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable t (8.5)."

In your code you are attempting static_cast with 'T = B*' and 'e = A*'

Now 'B* t(A*)' is not well-formed in C++ (but 'A* t(B*)' is because 'A' is a virtual unambiguous and accessible base of 'B'. Therefore the code gives error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is "safe" but.

Assuming

B derived from A (and A pure virtual)

Since I KNOW that a pointer to B still remains a pointer to B.

```
    class A
    {
            virtual void doSomething(const void* p) const =0;
    };

    class B
    {
    public:
            int value;
            virtual void doSomething(const void*p)const
            {
            const B * other = reinterpret_cast<const B*>(p);
            cout<<"hello!"<< other->value <<endl;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
            B  foo(1),bar(2);
            A * p = &foo, q=&bar;
            p->doSomething(q);
            return 0;
    }
```

this program executes and correctly return printing "hello!" and the value of the other object (in this case "2").

by the way, what I'm doing is highly unsafe (personally I give a different ID to every class and I assert after reinterpret casting that current ID is equal to other ID to be sure we are doing something with 2 equal classes) and as you see I limited myself to "const" methods. Thus this will work with "non-const" methods, but if you do something wrong catching the bug will be almost unpossible. And even with assertion there's a 1 chance out of 4 billions to succeed assertion even when it is supposed to fail
(assert(ID== other->ID);)

By the way.. A good OO design should not require this kinda of stuff, but in my case I tried to refactor/re-design the code without being able to drop the usage of reinterpret casting. generally speaking you CAN avoid this kind of things.

Comment: Are you sure this is necessary?

Comment: that's specific to your problem. a re-design should prevent this in most cases (avoid my example if you can). oh dear I forget a "const".

Comment: I mean are you sure you need it? What if I give doSomething an int pointer? That would fail disastrously. Why not use a dynamic cast, and check the result? I don't know what your exact requirements are, but I believe, if you bring in the static polymorphism system (e.g. CRTP pattern) you can come up with something safer.

Comment: static polymorphism is not suitable in lot of cases, anyway in my actual code I'm doing that in a type-safe way, so users have no chance to passa "int*" around. Originally I had a "ID" system, but I found later better system.. still times faster than a dynamic cast.

Comment: if you are still interested how that code can be usefull you can take a look at a my recent project. void* tricks are used in more than one place.: http://code.google.com/p/infectorpp/