# How to cast from virtual abstract class

Tags: visual-c++

Having this class definition

```
class CefBrowser : public virtual CefBase
```

How to cast from CefBrwoser * to CefBase * and reverse? assuming that both are not instanciable, they are loaded from C to CPP.

Comment: Can you clarify how are you loading a class from C? I don't understand.

Comment: They have been wrapped, from C dll, the problem is that i am upgrading the old Java wraper (2010) with the last CEF 1 (2013) but in the last version the CefBase interface become virtual, so old functions that haves CefBase * parameter can't accept derived classes any more, my first solution is to add another parameter long to send the pointer throw jni, finnally its working but i think that i should keep the question because i want to know if its possible to cast from virtual classes.
 
i am more specialised in Java, so may be my question isn't clear

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747066/c-cannot-convert-from-base-a-to-derived-type-b-via-virtual-base-a