# curiously recurring template pattern and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp, static-polymorphism

I am using the [curiously recurring template pattern to model static polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism).

This works absolutely fine, until one introduces `virtual inheritance` (to address a `diamond problem`).

Then the compiler (Visual Studio 2013) starts complaining about

`error C2635: cannot convert a 'Base*' to a 'Derived*'; conversion from a virtual base class is implied`

Basically, this conversion is [not allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b534kw.aspx).

Why is that? Both `static_cast` and `c-style cast` fail.

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve giving up one or the other?

EDIT:

Here a sample (remove the virtual and it works):

```
template <class Derived> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};

struct Derived : virtual Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation() { std::cout << "hello"; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.interface();
}
```

Comment: May be you have an XY-problem. You should elaborate why you need it virtual.

Comment: Maybe it is oversimplified for the example, but why not just use a private virtual function, i.e. Template Method pattern?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747066/c-cannot-convert-from-base-a-to-derived-type-b-via-virtual-base-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I found out, these can't be combined.

The point of the `curiously recurring template pattern` is to resolve the call at compile time.

As pointed out by T.C. in the comments, `virtual inheritance` can't be resolved until run-time.

Which means the two don't mix, and one has to give.

Comment: P.S. If anyone ever has a similar issues, I ended up replacing the diamond with `C++ mixins`.

Comment: virtual inheritance *is* to be resolved at run-time.