# How to solve a mesh inheritance problem in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following set of classes that inherit from each other in a mesh way. In the top level, I have abstract classes. Both `Abstract_Class_B` and `Abstract_Class_C` inherit from `Abstract_Class_A`.

In the second level of inheritance, I have the exact implementations of those classes.

1. `Impl_Class_A` inherits from `Abstract_Class_A`.
2. `Impl_Class_B` inherits from both `Abstract_Class_B` and `Impl_Class_A`.
3. `Impl_Class_C` inherits from both `Abstract_Class_C` and `Impl_Class_A`.

When I compile the below code, the compiler compiles perfectly if I do not declare any class in the code. But when I start declaring pointer to the classes in the second level, the compiler gives the following error:

```
undefined reference to `VTT for ns3::Impl_Class_B'
undefined reference to `vtable for ns3::Impl_Class_B'
```

I used `virtual` to tackle the typical diamond problem in inheritance, but I am still not able to compile. It makes sense that the compiler gets confused because of this way of inheritance. But my system requires such a design for those classes. Any solution to fix this problem?

The code:

```
// Top Level (Level 1)

class Abstract_Class_A
{
};

class Abstract_Class_B: virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
  public:
  uint8_t type;
};

class Abstract_Class_C: virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
};

// Second Level (Level 2)
class Impl_Class_A : virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
  public:
  double angle;
};

class Impl_Class_B: virtual public Abstract_Class_B, Impl_Class_A
{
};

class Impl_Class_C: virtual public Abstract_Class_C, Impl_Class_A
{
};

void test()
{
  Impl_Class_B* test = new Impl_Class_B ();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why I got -1, at least the person who did that should mention the reason if there is something unclear

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. What compiler/compiler options are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be related to other virtual functions inside the original classes that I had in my code. The code above works without any problem. During the development, I had encountered other problems so I post her a new code that solves all these problems with comments mentioned next to them:

```
// Top Level (Level 1)

class Abstract_Class_A
{
     ~Abstract_Class_A (); // To solve source type is not polymorphic” when trying to use dynamic_cast
};

class Abstract_Class_B: virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
  public:
  uint8_t type;
};

class Abstract_Class_C: virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
};

// Second Level (Level 2)
class Impl_Class_A : virtual public Abstract_Class_A
{
  public:
  double angle;
};

class Impl_Class_B: virtual public Abstract_Class_B, virtual public Impl_Class_A // Missing second virtual
{
};

class Impl_Class_C: virtual public Abstract_Class_C, virtual public Impl_Class_A // Missing second virtual
{
};

void test()
{
  Impl_Class_B* test = new Impl_Class_B ();
}
```

**Notes:**

1. With this type of inheritance paradigm, you cannot use `static_cast` but rather `dynamic_cast` should be used. Check the following [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747066/c-cannot-convert-from-base-a-to-derived-type-b-via-virtual-base-a).
2. When using `dynamic_cast` you should add a virtual destructor to the top class. Check the following [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114093/getting-source-type-is-not-polymorphic-when-trying-to-use-dynamic-cast) about it.

Comment: A `virtual` destructor is basically required as soon as you introduce a `virtual` method or the compiler might not know how to delete your derived objects.